# No able to run Elmah on .Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

I' m using Elmah  https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah.mvc for a MVC .net project.
For log/in the error I'm using MS SQL.

After installing the Database and installing Elmah through NutGet, I'not able to visualize the error in the database.

Here my Web.Config could you tell me what I'm doingwrong here? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
      -->
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="elmah">
          <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
          <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
          <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
          <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="MyProjectEventsMobileEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EventsCustom.csdl|res://*/Models.EventsCustom.ssdl|res://*/Models.EventsCustom.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyProjectEventsMobile;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
        <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
        <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>
        <membership>
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="false">
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <pages>
          <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
          </namespaces>
        </pages>
        <httpModules>
          <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
          <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
          <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
        </httpModules>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
          <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
          <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <elmah></elmah>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: what happens when you navigate to http://yoursite.com/elmah.axd ?

Comment: when I navigate to yoursite.com/elmah.axd I see the Elmah Page but with no error"No errors found. " I used Install-Package Elmah.MVC to install Elmah... any idea?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure elmah to use your database for the logging:

In your config extend `<elmah></elmah>` to:

```
<elmah>                  
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" 
        connectionStringName="MyProjectEventsMobileEntities" />
</elmah>
```

You can find more option in the ELMAH [sample web.config](http://elmah.googlecode.com/svn/tags/REL-1.2-SP1/samples/web.config) and in the [ErrorLogImplementations](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorLogImplementations)  wiki article.

Comment: Thanks fr your hint, I was able to fix the problem!